# Django manytomanyfield with through model override through queryset

Tags: django

I have a project in progress and it has one model that contains manytomany field. It worked as expected but I want to change the queryset through uses for some purpose.

`A.field.all() -> 1,2,3,4,5` will change to `A.field.all() -> 1,2,5` when I do that. How can I change this behaviour?

Comment: Question is not clear, can you please add more information?